# Can't print HP Envy 7640

Tags: printing

Since yesterday, got the new version 18.04.1, my network printer doesn't print. Work fine before...  Now inactive message. with filter problem. When I install the printer it looks for drivers, but can't find any.

Comment: Maybe installing/reinstalling HPLIP is what you need?

Comment: I did but still get a Inactive - Filter failed message. There is something blocking the info to the printer

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to get a HP Color LaserJet 2600n (by IP/JetDirect) and a super-old HP LaserJet 1010 (by USB) working in Kubuntu 18.04. I had to use another account first to run "hp-setup" (even though both accounts have Admin privileges and are sudoers). Only then could I install the printers using my normal account (weird). The LaserJet 1010 even auto-installed.